# Android Architecture Components: dataBinding not changing TextView value

Tags: android, xml, mvvm, data-binding

Hi I'm giving a try on new Architecture Components for Android, I've built a simple app and now I want to bind a Texview to a variable in my ViewModel, I did this before but I wasn't using the Components. now  The getter is not called and the value of the TextView is not changed.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleOwner {

    public MainViewModel viewModel;
```

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private LatLng origin;

public LatLng getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="jacopo.com.carbook.MainActivity">
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="jacopo.com.carbook.MainViewModel" />
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{Double.toString(viewModel.origin.latitude)}"/>
</layout
```

dataBinding is enabled in the gradle file so I'm not sure what's going on here as it's the same code of the previous version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

did you add this lines to your activity (according ti your file's names):

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_xml);
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ActivityViewModel.class);

binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
```